# No me muestra los resultados de una transacción

Tags: python-3.x, poo

Hola a todos bueno hoy vengo acá para pedirle que me ayuden y es que nose cual seria el problema de este programa no me muestra ni el saldo ni tampoco las demás transacciones correspondiente este codigo lo hice en php en la Universidad pero lo quise pasarlo a Python porque lo ando estudiando por aparte

```
class Banco ():
def __init__(self,Saldo,NombreC,NoCuenta):
    self.Sal=Saldo
    self.nom=NombreC
    self.ncuenta=NoCuenta
def getSaldo(self):
    if(self.Sal!=""):
        return self.Sal
    else:
        return "NO ha digitado ningun saldo"
def setSaldo (self,Saldo):
     self.Sal=Saldo
def Consignar(self,agg):
    resul=self.getSaldo()+agg
    return resul
def Retirar(self,vretiro):
    if(self.getSaldo()>=vretiro):
        re=self.getSaldo()-vretiro
        return re
    else:
        return "Saldo Insuficiente"
def Estado(self):
    return "Su saldo es: ",self.getSaldo()
cajero=Banco(10000000,"Emeterio",1234567)
cajero.Estado()
cajero.Consignar(7000000)
cajero.Retirar(5000000)
```

por cierto si alguno tiene algun documento en español del funcionamiento del getter y setter que me pueda facilitar se lo agradeceria aun no entiendo como funcionan

Comment: ¿Qué resultado esperas obtener, o en dónde no te _muestra_ los resultados?.

Comment: Por un lado, la identación de tu código no parece la correcta, tal vez es un error de copiar y pegar. Aún así, todos lo métodos solo retornan un valor, no lo imprimen. Para ver el resultado, debieras hacer algo así: `print(cajero.Estado())`, igual con los otros métodos.

Comment: :O patricio gracias era solo eso que error tan bobo de mi parte

Comment: Breynner, sobre los setter/getters, en Python no existen esos conceptos como tal, como tampoco el de atributos privados/públicos. Cualquier método o desde cualquier lado se puede acceder a un atributo mediante `instanci.attr`. Si se necesita una funcionalidad similar Python ofrece las `propiedades`, en el documentación tienes un ejemplo: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property.